# How do I set terminal ctrl+c (interrupt) to super+c

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal

How do I set `ctrl`+`c` (interrupt) to `super`+`c` in terminal?

- Any other key combination for sending the interrupt is unacceptable.
- Modifying the behavior of `ctrl` & `super` outside of the context of terminal (such as using gnome-tweaks to flip them around) is unacceptable. `ctrl` must remain as `ctrl` and `super` must remain as `super`.

Comment: The design of the the GNOME desktop environment is to have Super be the "system" modifier key - so if that key is in fact acting like the Super key (and not reconfigured to mimic the Ctrl key, as you mentioned you don't want to do), then gnome-shell is intercepting any single press of that key, and any key combinations, because it's expecting those to be system-level shortcuts. What task are you looking to accomplish that so strictly requires those two specific keys to mean "interrupt"?

Comment: Not easily. See https://superuser.com/questions/1178542/super-key-notation-for-stty

Comment: @johnandmegh I am looking to unify common hotkey behavior across the OSs I'll regularly be using. It was easy enough to ensure windows muscle memory is transferrable to macOS by swapping the `ctrl` and `cmd` keys which macOS has an option for. However, transferring that to Ubuntu seems more challenging because the terminal hotkey preferences don't include a binding for `0x03` interrupt, instead silently moving it around on conflict.

Comment: @thornofcamorr I was able to get used to the different keybindings pretty quickly. Remember that Ctrl+C for interrupt is a very old standard and deeply ingrained in the muscle memory of all terminal users worldwide. Sometimes it's easier to go with the flow. Just saying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make sure to overcome the obstacle mentioned in
@johnandmegh's comment. Somehow configure your windowing environment, or pick a different shortcut key.

Should you decide to use `Ctrl`+`C` for copy and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`C` for interrupt, i.e. swap these two keys from their original behavior, you can simply set `Ctrl`+`C` as the copy's hotkey in GNOME Terminal's Preferences and you're done.

If you want something different, you will probably have to modify the terminal's (in fact [VTE](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/)'s) source. This assumes that you have some basic knowledge of the C (C++ actually) programming language, as well as software or package installation.

You may need to edit `keymap.cc`, but more likely `Terminal::widget_key_press()` in `vte.cc`. It seems to me that the relevant part is where the comment says `Replace characters which have "control" counterparts with those counterparts.`

The terminal needs to emit a one-byte control character, and `stty intr` has to be configured to this value. Go with the byte 0x03 if you don't want to touch `stty` (and deal with other possible conflicts there).

Compile VTE and try with `./src/app/vte-2.91`. If it doesn't work, place `printf()`s in the source to understand what's happening. If it works, you should probably follow Ubuntu's build procedure to compile the same version as shipped by Ubuntu, apply Ubuntu's patches too, the same compile options and so on. Anyway, somehow you should replace the system-wide VTE installation with this version, then quit *all* `gnome-terminal` windows at once. If you break something, start up a non-VTE-based terminal and reinstall the distro's `libvte-2.91-0` and related packages from there.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the time to catch up on c++ and learn how to compile & install my own version of VTE but this looks to me like the correct answer. I'm just baffled that what you've directed me to add isn't already supported out of the box by the Ubuntu terminal. It already allows you to rebind copy, paste, and others, it should include `0x03`/interrupt in its binding list.

Comment: GNOME Terminal allows you to configure the shortcuts related to using its own graphical interface, not the ones related to terminal emulation. The byte 0x03 is the de facto "Ctrl+C character", very few people want to override this. There are some terminal emulators out there that allow you to configure everything but the kitchen sink, trying to address each and every user's special one-off request. This is not GNOME's philosophy.

Comment: "very few people want to override this" - you mean, anyone who wants to be able to copy paste like normal?

Comment: Traditionally both features (copy and interrupt) are Ctrl+C, and traditionally, _in graphical terminals_, the way to resolve it is to move the copy functionality to Shift+Ctrl+C. Some people swap the two, which you can also easily do. Using Super+C for interrupt is not a standard solution at all, especially because the window manager likely interferes with it, as already mentioned.

Comment: I'm sorry but tradition has no place getting in the way of accessibility and customizability. Especially for something as trivial as a key mapping.

Comment: This forum is for discussing how software works and how to achieve your goal;
not for discussing how _you think_ a certain piece of software _should_ work.
The current situation is indeed bad. No one knows how to fix it. For example,
changing interrupt to Super+C (and presumably the same for all other letters?)
will break consistency/usability of terminal-based applications, their help
pages and websearch results that tell to press Ctrl+C (or any other
Ctrl+letter). Fine for you as a personal hack, not fine to be shipped in a
product. [...]

Comment: I've been developing GNOME Terminal and VTE, and following forum topics about
them, on and off for a decade now. You're the second person I recall looking
for a single key modifier for both use cases. When I say very few people are
interested, trust me, I have _some_ clue what I'm talking about. [...]

Comment: "as trivial as a key mapping" It's really nontrivial. Each key can generate
many different codes, depending on modifiers and other states. Allowing to
configure each of these, via an API due to the G-T vs. VTE separation, would
be quite a programming task to begin with; let alone presenting it as an easy
to understand and easy to use UI. (I hope you don't mean that we should ship a
solution specific to _your_ exact preferences, rather than a generic one.) And
then we still haven't talked about how the desktop environment will get out of
the way and not handle Super+letters. [...]

Comment: GNOME is (in)famous for providing only a small set of configuration options,
the ones that many users are looking for. Generic keyboard mapping just
doesn't fit this picture, and also the time it would take to develop it is
rather spent on other features. You may not be happy with this, but you won't
change the project's direction. As a co-developer of this software I rarely
recommend this, but maybe you should be looking for a different terminal that
provides the flexibility you're looking for.

Comment: Ctrl+C for interrupt in terminals existed decades before microsuck imposed their malware-infested malware garbage on the entire world. Which was a ripoff of the early apple/mac computers in the first place.